# Is a continuous monotone function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ necessarily unbounded?

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and monotonically increasing (or decreasing). $f(0)=0$. Does $f$ necessarily attain all possible values in $\mathbb{R}$? i.e. is $f$ onto?

Comment: Do note boundness and ontoness aren't equivalent not even in this specific conditions.

Comment: But if it's not unbounded it can never be onto, right?

Comment: That's correct. But it can be unbounded and not be onto ($x\mapsto e^x$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \arctan(x)$.  That should do it, no?

Comment: Thanks! So it could be bounded, but in that case its range would be an interval (since continuous) and within that interval it's onto right?

Comment: Yes, its range would be an interval, but it is trivially/automatically onto there by the definition of range.